# Can we give some tolerance to those new users?

Tags: discussion

The *StackEchange* is a complicated website for new user as I see it, which has many original rules and some styles for old user. I think we can have;some patience for new user, don't downvote them easily, please.

Such as this post

[Plotiing of the ASCII file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141231/plotiing-of-the-ascii-file)

Well I don't think we should give `-1` without any suggestion, which will confuse  and scare away the OP, but any community need new user actually.

Comment: "I don't think we should give -1 without any suggestion" That is generally true. A downvote should be explained, unless it is obvious enough to the OP. It is also important to help new users learn how to use this site. However, the question you linked to was of pretty bad quality, despite the user having been active here for a month.  It is difficult to strike a good balance between preventing leeching (with all the devastating effects it can have on a community) and helping new people integrate.

Comment: Szabolcs handled this the right way. He saw a downvoted post and he explained to the OP why it was downvoted. This to me is the recommended course of action, nothing else needs to be done or can be done.

Comment: @C.E. Yes,Szabolcs do that in a right way,I mean those just give a downvote and leave.Especially a new user will confusing about that.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/on-downvotes-for-new-users

Comment: @yode Well that's what I meant with "nothing else ... can be done". Some people think downvoting is enough. What can those of us who think downvoting alone is not enough, because OP  may not understand what the downvote is about? We can add a comment. I think it resolves the problem (which exists only from our point of view, we should remember that it does not exist from the point of view of people who think the explanations are unnecessary. We create the problem and we solve it.)

Comment: @C.E. What you say is seem to make sense indeed..

Comment: I strongly recommend not downvoting new users. leave them a link, wait for some time, and close the question would be more proper. Closing these questions after sometime won't mess the site as these problems will eventually be closed, but it is more comfortable for new users comparing to downvotes. For new users, some useful links, a small piece of advice would be be a sign of welcome, a close after a few days seldom matters. however, a direct downvote can be really harmful because they would interpret this as:"Your question is just nonsense, we discuss more 'significant' problems here!"

Comment: Approximately 4 years ealier, when I still know nothing except the simplest equation solving in Mathematica, I tried to asked a question here. I dare say that's not a good one at all: poor English + naive question. I got an answer, a fairly good one, but I got a lot of downvotes. For a newbie to SE and Mathematica, I felt like I need years to fix those rep subtracted, so I left. After two years of low-efficiency struggling with Mathematica, I got back here and find out I would be much more experienced if I haven't left, also I found that those negative reps will disappear with deletion.

Comment: But as a new user, I won't know anything about those stuffs, and the only thing I will feel is I'm not welcomed here, this place is for the experienced GODS of Mathematica! I believe none of us here would like to give new users this feeling, so I suggest leave suggestions and links, and simply close the question after sometime, don't downvote, downvotes does no good at all.

Comment: I will confess to downvoting a recent question from a relatively new user not because of the question being asked but because repeated requests for information were explicitly ignored.  The only responses I could get were that their result was "totally wrong" (without giving their "totally wrong" result) and "I will add an example to show what is going on" (where the code was given but still no output as to what was wrong).  I even voted to close.  I probably should have shown more patience.  (But the vast majority of new users aren't like that particular OP.)

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  I've been a MMa user for a couple of years now, and wow was this site difficult that first year or so.

Comment: @JerryGuern This site is very good,though there are some no good manner case.

Comment: I would argue that it's not unacceptable to downvote questions like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140945/find-the-following-plots-area) or those with a pile of code, poor description and ask you to debug

Comment: Personally I must strongly disagree with people saying, that this site were too harsh to newcomers. While it has an elaborate learning path for newbies, I have found it exceedingly nice and welcoming. So much so, that I was rather awestruck at the harshness I have experienced on other sites like Cross Validated and Meta Stackexchange. On CV I got an answer downvoted because it was correct but not a complete solution to the question in all cases - just telling... Mostly I prefer not to vote, post a comment or to raise a close vote instead. This community by and large works rather nicely imo.

Comment: Note that the site was not created for rank beginners: ["...some proof of minimal Mathematica knowledge: be familiar with the language, its syntax, and the ways you can look for help. The searchable Documentation Center is included with Mathematica, and contains a full language reference, tutorials and guides."](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @JimBaldwin If the user comes back and does not respond to my question or suggestion, I almost always downvote. They're just being rude and not participating in a constructive process. If they then respond and edit their question, I can un-downvote. In many cases, I'll upvote to encourage such participation, even if the improved question is still not interesting.  If they disagree and we cannot come to some resolution, I might just leave it alone. Honest disagreements are possible, and I think that's outside the purpose of downvotes.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm a SE user for some years,but I just know *the site was not created for rank beginners.*

Comment: @wjx With all due respect, you're exactly the type of user deserving downvote(s) 4 years ago. I clearly remember you're not downvoted at the very beginning, people (not only here, but also in our Chinese forum) were trying to tell you the proper way to participate in this site, but you didn't give any effective response and keep posting low quality questions and answers and even created sock puppets!

Comment: @wjx Maybe it was all because of your poor English (and Chinese, perhaps, you're only 13 years old at that time), but it's not our business, it's blameless to downvote a seemingly incommunicable user keeping generating low quality posts.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'd answer but it would contain 80% of copy paste from your comments. Would be so kind to move them to the answer so people can upvote? :)

Comment: I consider myself both, a beginner with Mathematica and a newcomer to this website. I find the community here very helpful and patient, and would strongly disagree that people are not tolerant. If I write a stupid question or fail to respond to correct issues pointed by other users, I personally find it very incentivizing if somebody clearly says that without wrapping it in a 'politically-correct speech' (one should distinguish this from being insulting). After all, it is insulting to the community members here if one ignores comments by the experienced users (which is mostly the case here).